# Knockout Computed with Parameter not updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

In a MVC application im generating multiple dropdowns from the database:

```
<select data-bind="options: findGroup(1).items(),
                        optionsText: 'country',
                        optionsValue: 'id',
                        value: selectedItem(1),
                        event: { change: selectionChange }"></select>
```

I need the current selected in my code, but for Debugging puroses im using a span:

```
<span data-bind="text: 'Computed Selected Country: ' + selectedItem(1).country"></span><br />
```

the findgroup(x) and the selectedItem(x) are global functions in my ViewModel while those are for all the dropdowns the same.

the selectedItem(x) should return the currently selected Option of the dropdown.
selectedItem(x) is a function to return a computed knockout observable. the selectedItem(x) always Returns "undefined", cant figure out why...

full example: http://jsfiddle.net/LGveR/17/

TIA,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns a computed so it needs to be executed like,

http://jsfiddle.net/LGveR/18/

```
this.selectedItem(1)().country
```

Comment: Great, Thank you, obvious, but overlooked :)

Comment: Btw, its not very KO-like to create a new computed each time the selection changes. A computed should track the change, but it should not be recreated